# Tor safe site directory

Tags: onion-services, website

Hello my question to the community. Is there a directory of safe websites that starts in Tor? I used Tor long ago and there was a directory of safe websites that helped newbies explore the web under Tor but now I can't seem to find any way to explore the deep web. Help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'safe websites that starts in Tor"? You mean the `.onion` sites?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "safe websites that starts in Tor" you mean the `.onion` sites. If that is the case there are several 'directory' websites that lists the links to different hidden services and .onion deep web links, for example, [Hidden Wiki](http://thehiddenwiki.org/) and [OnionDir](https://dirnxxdraygbifgc.onion.to/).